# Django form JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

Please tell me where the problem is:
 I need to process a JSON request, what should I access and what should I return?  and this is the essence of the problem, because the answer comes to me on the server, that there is a problem with the token.

**contact.html:**

```
<form class="feedback__form" id="contact_form" role="form" action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="feedback__inv-msg feedback__response-msg">
    <span> ERROR</span>
  </div>
  <div class="feedback__form-wrapper">
    <ul class="feedback__field-list">
      <li class="feedback__field-item">
        <div class="feedback__field-title txt txt_font_mp_regular txt_size_18"><span>YOUR NAME</span></div>
        <div class="feedback__field-inp">
          {{ contact_form.contact_name }}
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="feedback__field-item">
        <div class="feedback__field-title txt txt_font_mp_regular txt_size_18"><span>YOUR MAIL</span></div>
    <div class="feedback__field-inp">
        {{ contact_form.contact_email }}
  </div>
  <li class="feedback__field-item">
    <div class="feedback__field-title txt txt_font_mp_regular txt_size_18"><span>YOUR PHONE</span></div>
<div class="feedback__field-inp">
    {{ contact_form.contact_phone }}
</div>
  <li class="feedback__field-item">
    <div class="feedback__field-title txt txt_font_mp_regular txt_size_18"><span>YOUR PROBLEM</span></div>
    <div class="feedback__field-inp">
      {{ contact_form.content }}
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="feedback__controls">
    <button class="btn btn_compact feedback__sender" type="submit">SEND</button>
  </div>
  <div class="feedback__response">
  <div class="feedback__positive feedback__response-msg"><span>YOUR MESSAGE WAS SENT</span></div>
  <div class="feedback__negative feedback__response-msg"><span>YOUR MESSAGE WASNT SENT</span></div>
</div>
</form>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  class Form {
    constructor(){
      this.element = document.querySelector(`.feedback`)
      this.init()
      this.isValid = false
      this.values = {}
    }

    addClassesToImps(){
      for(let elem of this.element.querySelectorAll(`input`))
      elem.classList.add(`inp`)
      this.element.querySelector(`input[type="hidden"]`).classList.remove(`inp`)
    }

    getStructure(){
      this.addClassesToImps()
      this.form = this.element.querySelector(`.feedback__form`)
      this.inps = this.element.querySelectorAll(`.inp`)
      this.reqInps = this.element.querySelectorAll(`.inp[required]`)
      this.sender = this.element.querySelector(`.feedback__sender`)
    }

    handleValidityCheck(elem){
      if(!elem.checkValidity()){
        elem.classList.add(`inp_invalid`)
        this.isValid = false
      } else {
        elem.classList.remove(`inp_invalid`)
        elem.classList.add(`inp_valid`)
      }
    }

    handleSenderClick(e){

      e.preventDefault()

      this.isValid = true
      for(let elem of this.reqInps){
        this.handleValidityCheck(elem)
      }
      if(this.isValid){
        this.element.classList.remove(`feedback_inv`)

        this.values.name = this.element.querySelector(`.inp[name="contact_name"]`).value
        this.values.mail = this.element.querySelector(`.inp[name="contact_email"]`).value
        this.values.phone = this.element.querySelector(`.inp[name="contact_phone"]`).value
        this.values.text = this.element.querySelector(`.inp[name="content"]`).value

        async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
          const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
            body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
          });
          return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
        }

        postData(``, this.values)
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
          });

      } else {
        this.element.classList.add(`feedback_inv`)
        return false
      }

    }

    init(){
      this.getStructure()
      console.log(this)
      this.sender.addEventListener(`click`, this.handleSenderClick.bind(this))
      for(let elem of this.inps){
        elem.addEventListener(`focusout`, this.handleValidityCheck.bind(this, elem))
      }

    }
  }

  let feedback = new Form()
</script>
```

**forms.py:**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    contact_phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'my_field', 'class': 'feedback__textarea inp'})
    )

    # the new bit we're adding
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Name:"
        self.fields['contact_email'].label = "Mail:"
        self.fields['contact_phone'].label = "Phone"
        self.fields['content'].label = "Your problem"
```

**views.py:**

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
            , '')
            contact_phone = request.POST.get(
                'contact_phone'
            , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
            , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'contact_phone': contact_phone,
                'form_content': form_content,
            }
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New message from form",
                content,
                '', ['mail@mail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('')
```

**in urls.py:**

```
...
path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
...
```

**in server console:**

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 403
```

**in browser console:**

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Please do not recommend options using jQuery, its presence is excluded in this project

Comment: You need to look up django csrf. You need to send csrf token with your post requests. Your form actually has csrf token but on JS side you are not properly sending it.

Answer (score 1):

In your script take the csrf token value using the below line

`var token = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();`

and when you sending data to server use one more parameter

```
headers: {'X-CSRFToken': token}
```

It will resolve your csrf error and make sure in form you have defined {% csrf_token %}.